# How do you make a silenced exception for async/await?

Tags: c#, exception, async-await

I've heard that the exceptions in fire & forget async calls are swallowed. However, that is not the case I experience with the example below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foo();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }

    static async void foo()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                throw new Exception();
            });
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown, causing fail-fast. I do not know whether GC causes the exception to be thrown while it collects the objects.

In what kind of code examples do developers experience unobserved, silenced exceptions in async/await code?

Comment: Note that your `async` method isn't awaiting anything, so you shouldn't be marking it as `async` at all, as the compiler warning you're getting is telling you.

Comment: @TomK: In the code you posted, the exception *is* silently swallowed. You're probably just seeing the debugger notify you of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Whether task exceptions are swallowed or not depends on the .NET version and a setting. Starting with 4.5 they are default ignored. Don't change that default. Don't change process-wide settings. Rather, go with the times.

A GC triggers the fail-fast behavior. Don't rely on that.

In your example, you have used async void which alters behavior again. It posts exceptions to the current sync context. Here, there is none. Do not use async void.

Nesting a `Task.Factory.StartNew` in an async method creates a completely separate task. Your async method has no point.

Answer (score 0):

When an unhandled exception occurs inside of a running Task, it's stored until it is observed. There are several ways to observe an unhandled task exception. Invoking `Wait()`, getting `Exception` of `Task` object or getting `Result` of `Task<T>` object.

> If you don’t give a faulted task the opportunity to propagate its exceptions the > runtime will
>   escalate the task’s unobserved exceptions according to the current
>   .NET exception policy when the task is garbage-collected. Unobserved
>   task exceptions will eventually be observed in the finalizer
>   thread context. If an unhandled exception is thrown during the execution of a Finalize
>   method, the runtime will, by default, terminate the current process,
>   and no active try/finally blocks or additional finalizers will be
>   executed, including finalizers that release handles to unmanaged resources.

It's from `Parallel Programming with Microsoft .NET` book.

However, since .NET 4.5 the default behaviour is that unobserved exceptions are "swallowed": not thrown in finalization context, and do not terminate the process. It can be changed by the following configuration flag:

```
<configuration> 
    <runtime> 
        <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/> 
    </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

Async/await methods are translated by compiler into code that uses `Task<T>` objects, particularly `await` will be translated into something like:

```
(.. everything before await...).ContinueWith(...the rest of the method...)
```

which internally will call one of the mentioned above: `Wait()` or `Result` and observe exception. But when you run "fire & forget" tasks (which is not the case when you use `await`) with `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` and never wait for it or await it, any unhandled exception that occurs in it will be unobserved. So, generally, it's considered a bad practice to do so.